# Programming Python by Mark Lutz Chapter 1 error

Tags: python

I a working through Mark Lutz's programming python book, and in chapter one I keep getting an error when I try to run a script. Here is his code from the book:

```
    dbfilename = 'people-file'
    ENDDB = 'enddb.'
    ENDREC = 'endrec.'
    RECSEP = '=>'

    def storeDbase(db, dbfilename=dbfilename):
        "formatted dump of databse to flat file"
        dbfile = open(dbfilename, 'w')
        for key in db:
            print(key, file=dbfile)
            for (name, value) in db[key].items():
                print(name + RECSEP + repr(value), file=dbfile)
            print(ENDREC, file=dbfile)
        print(ENDDB, file=dbfile)
        dbfile.close()

    def loadDbase(dbfilename=dbfileame):
        "parse data to reconstruct database"
        dbfile = open(dbfilename)
        import sys
        sys.stdin = dbfile
        db = {}
        key = input()
        while key != ENDDB:
            rec = {}
            field = input()
            while field != ENDREC:
                name, value = field.split(RECSEP)
                rec[name] = eval(value)
                field = input()
            db[key] = rec
            key = input()
        return db

    if __name__== '__main__':
        for initdata import db
        storeDbase(db)
```

When I run the script, this is the error I keep getting:

```
-> Programming_Python  python make_db_file.py
   Welcome to Python! Lets do something cool
  File "make_db_file.py", line 17
    print(key, file=dbfile)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone help me understand what's wrong with the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't run Python 3 code in Python 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using two different versions of python. Try upgrading to python 3, and see if that helps:

python 2:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]'
>>> print('hi', file=open('file.txt', 'w'))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print('hi', file=open('file.txt', 'w'))
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

python 3:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.4.0b2 (v3.4.0b2:ba32913eb13e, Jan  5 2014, 11:02:52) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]'
>>> print('hi', file=open('file.txt', 'w'))
>>>
```

**In python3, `print` is a *function*, meaning you can pass in parameters. However, in python2, it is a *statement*, meaning you can't pass in parameters.**

Comment: Downvoter, why the down vote? (To all others, the vote count is +1/-2)

Comment: @user142900, if this answer helped you, would you mind +1'ing it and accepting it by clicking on the green check next to my answer? It gives you **+2 reputation :)**

Comment: it did help! But i can't upvote it cause i don't have enough karma. Not sure what to do about that.

Comment: @user142900 No problem, you can still click on the green check next to my answer.

Comment: **nevermind, I remembered. You type 'python3 _command or file_'. Duh. **Ok, so I am having trouble again. How do I run python 3 in the mac os x terminal? I was doing it before but now it won't work. What does the command look like?

Comment: Just type `which python`, and if that doesn't give the path to python3, you can set up an alias, or just type in `python3`.